# Horizontal scrollbar is not working on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I'm using the following html to show a select box. I want to show the select box with a fixed width and would like to see scrollbar if any option is longer. The following works on chrome and firefox but it does not work in safari.

Any ideas ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <style type="text/css">
             select.dualList {
             width:100%;
             height:300px;
             overflow-x: auto;
             }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <table>
             <tr >
                <td style="width:100px">
                   <select multiple="multiple" class="dualList" id="sourceList" >
                      <option value="item11">Item 1 This is my item 1. It should scroll</option>
                      <option value="item22">Item 2fsdsfsdf asdf asfsdas</option>
                      <option value="item33">Item 3</option>
                      <option value="item44">Item 4</option>
                      <option value="item55">Item 5</option>
                   </select>
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it does not work in my Firefox 47 (Windows 10 x86_64).

Second, as much as many of us would like to expect that the rendering of things like `select` elements only is done using CSS rules, it is not so and different browsers render them differently -- there is no cross browser requirement as to how `select` elements should be rendered *exactly*.

The downside of that is you don't know how it will look, so you simply cannot expect to have *exact* control of it. Trying to control it like that will result in nothing but frustration and is a futile exercise. I recommend you leave the control in the hands of your browser users -- rest assured it will be rendered in a way they are comfortable with. If your option text is too long, the browser will accommodate it somehow -- it usually stretches the list itself horizontally so people can read the entire text. The lesson you can take from that is to not have too much text.

If you are asking people to select sentences, perhaps radio buttons (`<input type="radio">`) are a better idea?